# Italian "Verismo" story: a farmer knows his wife cheats on him but he pretends he doesn't know it to avoid troubles

Tags: identification-request, short-stories, italian-language

I'm trying to find an Italian short story of the "Verismo" literary movement I read a long time ago and now I recall only partially: it's probably by Verga or Capuana or, less likely, Pirandello.
Pretty sure it isn't "Pentolaccia" despite the similar plot.

The story is set in the rural Sicily of the late 19th century.
The main character is an old/weak farmer married with a younger and beautiful wife.
He knows she cheats on him but he doesn't care as he doesn't want any troubles so whenever he comes back to town he sends a kid ahead to announce his return to the wife.   It's obviously a stunt to give her lover the time to leave the house unseen by him and avoid the confrontation he fears.

This works until a villager openly accuses the farmer of being cheated on, which requires him to act, although unwillingly: so one day he shows up home suddenly and actually finds his wife with her lover.
Now he must challenge the cheater to a knife fight but his younger opponent kills him easily.

Would anyone tell me the author and title of this story?

Comment: Did you read it in Italian? Do you know if it was translated in English?

Comment: Yes, I read it in Italian. And sadly I'm not aware whether this story was translated to English or not. I guess it was, as most of the works of the cited authors have been translated, but I'm not 100% positive.